# How to pull data from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I built a location-aware web application and used the W3C Geolocation API for detecting the location of a visitor and used the Google Maps API to display the map. How can I get data stored in mongodb that represent information about places near me to display above a place  when click it on the map?
for example:

```
db.places.insert({name:"",kind:"restaurant",serves:["Fast food","Sea food"],price:{fast food:200$,Sea food:175$}});
```

I want these information displayed when I click a restaurant on map.
When I click a restaurant's name on the map, I want to display these information above the restaurant's name.

Comment: are you using rails ?

Comment: You should change the title of this question

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start, you're gonna want to associate the restaurants with geo location data. If you have lat lon stored, then you can query using mongodb Geospatial queries:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/

Here is a sample from the docs:

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $near :
                           { $geometry :
                               { type : "Point" ,
                                 coordinates: [ 40 , 5 ] } },
                             $maxDistance : 500
                } } )
```